# xslt variable xpath expressions

Tags: xslt, xpath

Can someone help me out for the following solution:

```
<xsl:variable name="filterByNameA" select="*/person[firstName=$fname] "/>
```

I want to do this if possible

```
 <xsl:variable name="filterByNameA" select="*/person[firstName=$fname] and */person[secondName=$fname]"/>
```

In other words, I need to have two conditions in one variable in order to get me all of the `person` elements that have the same `firstName` and `secondName`.

Comment: You know, showing code that doesn't work isn't the best way of explaining your requirements. How are we supposed to know what you thought the code would do, given that this is different from what it actually does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the two tests inside the same predicate:

```
<xsl:variable name="filterByNameA" select="*/person[firstName=$fname and secondName=$fname]"/>
```

Or equivalently, use two predicates:

```
<xsl:variable name="filterByNameA" select="*/person[firstName=$fname][secondName=$fname]"/>
```

When you have consecutive predicates like that, each one filters the list that resulted from the one before, so they are effectively `and`ed together